# I am getting error on stream controller on flutter

Tags: flutter

When I open the app it opens, when I click on the image it opens but when I press back n again click on the image it throws an exception saying

> "Stream has already listened to".

Here is my code:

```
    StreamSubscription<T> _subscribe(void onData(T data), Function onError,
      void onDone(), bool cancelOnError) {
    if (!_isInitialState) {
      throw new StateError("Stream has already been listened to."); //here I get the exception
    }
    _ControllerSubscription<T> subscription = new _ControllerSubscription<T>(
        this, onData, onError, onDone, cancelOnError);

    _PendingEvents<T> pendingEvents = _pendingEvents;
    _state |= _STATE_SUBSCRIBED;
```

Comment: make sure you do not call `Stream#listen()` method on the same stream twice

Comment: @pskink I am very new so can you please tell where to put exactly?

Comment: check the stacktrace and find the first frame from the top that contains your code, what is it?

Comment: @pskink 
void addError(Object error, [StackTrace stackTrace]);
 Future close()